# Showing list results for today from a set of dates

Tags: list, column, date-time

I have created a list with:

- 1 column with a start date
- 1 column with an end date

I'd like to set up a view where it will check and show only the items where the current date is included between the dates in the above columns.

I can't use a 'greater or equal to' the end date because this shows any items in the future. I'm looking for just the entries valid on the current [Today] date.

Can anyone help at all?

I, sadly, don't have Designer and I'm using SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Combine the `End date greater than or equal to today` with `Start date less than or equal to today`, with `AND` between the filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build your filter to look like the following

[image]

Note : Replace Due date with End date